# Navbar div onclick function does not work for inner elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div class `.dropbtn` inside my navbar that I wish would run a list drop down function when clicked, but only the text `"TOTAL"` works onclick.

The `<span>` and the `<i>` inside it do not do anything when I click on it, and I need all three elements to be clickable and display the dropdown function. I am using jQuery, but not Bootstrap. Thanks in advance! EDITED.

```js
jQuery('body').on('click', '.dropbtn', function() {
  jQuery("#myDropdown").toggleClass("show");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="reservas_right">
  <div class="dropdown_reservas nav-item_reservas" id="inner_reservas_right">
    <div class="dropbtn">
      TOTAL
      <br /><span id="totalprice">0,00€</span>
      <i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-content_reservas" id="myDropdown">
      <ul id="dropul" class="dropul">
        <li id="drop1"></li>
        <li id="drop2"></li>
        <li id="drop3"></li>
        <li id="drop4"></li>
        <li id="drop5"></li>
        <li id="drop6"></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.show{
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.dropbtn', function(e) {
    if(e.target !== this && jQuery(e.target).parent().is(".dropbtn"))
    {
        jQuery("#myDropdown").toggleClass("show");
    } else {
        jQuery("#myDropdown").toggleClass("show");
    }
});
```

Comment: @SagarJajoriya please note that OP lacks the required 15 reputation to upvote.  You might consider upvoting their question to help them gain the needed reputation.

Comment: I was gonna say that haha, new so I don't have any reputation yet. I accepted your answer tho! :)